# assertTemplateUsed with django_jinja tries to match full path

Tags: django, unit-testing, jinja2

I've recently upgraded to Django 1.8, replacing the `jingo` adapter with `django_jinja` for working with Jinja2 templates. I have a few tests that look like this:

```
self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'staff/update_record.jinja')
```

These used to work, but now they fail because it seems to be comparing my string with the full path of the template rather than relative to the template directory:

```
AssertionError: Template 'staff/update_record.jinja' was not a template used to render the response. Actual template(s) used: /home/ben/Repos/myrepo/myproject/templates/staff/update_record.jinja
```

Is there something I need to add in `settings.TEMPLATES` or anywhere else to make this return the relative path rather than the absolute path?

Comment: Could you post `settings.TEMPLATES`?